# Translate select query to DAX expression

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

Im trying to convert some SQL queries to DAX, but I dont know where to start.

```
SELECT jobid,Fullname
FROM public."Data"  
WHERE jobid IN (
     SELECT jobid
     FROM public."Data"
     GROUP BY jobid
     HAVING max(case when Userid = '21' then 1 else 0 end) = 0) 
ORDER BY jobid ASC;
```

The data looks like this:
 [image]

I want the jobid rows where userid 21(Ed peanut) is not on the jobid (sorry for this vague explanation, my english is not that good).

So my result would look like this:
[image]

I think my SQL query does exactly this, but now I need it in DAX.
Could you guys help me out ? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can summarize the `jobid` values which contain the required `userid`, then use `NOT` and `IN` to filter your table:

```
NewTable = 
VAR ExcludeJobs = 
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS ( 
        Data[jobID],
        FILTER ( 
            Data,
            Data[Userid] = 21
        )
    )
RETURN
    FILTER ( 
        Data,
        NOT ( Data[jobID] IN ExcludeJobs )
    )
```